# Reducing the spaces before and after \smallsetminus

Tags: spacing

I recently found `\smallsetminus` as a much nicer alternative to just `\setminus`, which is essentially just a backslash.  However, I'm a bit unhappy with how much size it leaves before and after the `\` character.

Is there any way to reduce that space? Or a different alternative other than `\smallsetminus`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\setsmallminus` is a binary operator (packages `amssymb` or `MnSymbol`). Binary operators gets same space before and after (unless in script styles). The additional spaces are not inserted, if the symbol is an ordinary symbol. That can be achieved by a subformula:

```
A {\smallsetminus} B
```

Full example, extended:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[ A + B \]
\[ A \smallsetminus B \]
\[ A \!\smallsetminus\! B \]
\[ A {\smallsetminus} B \]
\[ \mathbb{I} \smallsetminus \{0\} \]
\[ \mathbb{I} \!\smallsetminus\! \{0\} \]
\[ \mathbb{I} {\smallsetminus} \{0\} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without the additional spaces of a binary operator the fourth and last lines look wrong to me. A compromise are the middle lines that reduce the spacing using `\!`.

Comment: I see what you mean, it also looks wrong to me.  But I don't like the second line either.  It looks particularly bad in the actual text I'm writing:  $\mathbb{I}\smallsetminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Middle lines are exactly what I needed, thank you.